# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3: integrating datetime picker with datetime select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, datetimepicker

In my Rails 4 app, I use default Rails forms and Bootstrap 3.

I am trying to replace the standard `datetime select` helper with [bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails):

[image]

I have found [this tutorial by Dave Hulihan](http://www.davehulihan.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker-and-rails/) explaining how to override the default Rails form helpers, but this was for a Rails 3 app:

```
# Add to config/initializers/form.rb or the end of app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder 
      def date_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_date = @object.send(method) 
        formatted_date = existing_date.to_date.strftime("%F") if existing_date.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_date, :class => "form-control datepicker", :"data-date-format" => "YYYY-MM-DD") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end

      def datetime_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_time = @object.send(method) 
        formatted_time = existing_time.to_time.strftime("%F %I:%M %p") if existing_time.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_time, :class => "form-control datetimepicker", :"data-date-format" => "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does this approach still make sense in Rails 4?

—————

**UPDATE**: I have added the above code to a new `config/initializers/form.rb` file.

My datetime field has been updated in the browser:

[image]

But the datetime picker is not working yet.

This the code from my view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

—————

Comment: I think your code should still work in rails 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Would you recommend to add it `inconfig/initializers/form.rb` or at the end of `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`? The tutorial does not specify and I am wondering whether there is a best practice here or not.

Comment: I think the better place would be in the initializers :)

Comment: Thanks! I would be happy if I could use it with this solution. Other solutions would be changing the time param in controller or using moment.js or american date gems. Of course all those solutions come with text_field. Here is the moment.js approach: https://www.codementor.io/ruby-on-rails/tutorial/localize-time-traditional-rails-app-momentjs-twitter-clone

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, with the precious help of **[Dave Hulihan](http://www.davehulihan.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker-and-rails/)** himself.

In `config/initializers/form.rb`:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder 
      def date_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_date = @object.send(method) 
        formatted_date = existing_date.to_date.strftime("%F") if existing_date.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_date, :class => "form-control datepicker", :"data-date-format" => "YYYY-MM-DD") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end

      def datetime_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
        existing_time = @object.send(method)
        existing_time ||= Time.now
        formatted_time = existing_time.to_time.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y %I:%M %p") if existing_time.present?
        @template.content_tag(:div, :class => "input-group") do    
          text_field(method, :value => formatted_time, :class => "form-control datetimepicker", :"data-date-format" => "dddd, MMMM DD YYYY hh:mm A") +
          @template.content_tag(:span, @template.content_tag(:span, "", :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar") ,:class => "input-group-addon")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then, in `app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
```

Now, the datetime picker is working like a charm.

Comment: Thibaud, have you tried to use 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A' format in the datetimepicker. If you have, then how could you convert it properly to avoid the issue that rails saves 01/05/2016 as 05/01/2016 into db?

Comment: Nope, I have not. And this is actually an excellent question. So far, I did not have any problem. But I will double-check and let you know if I find something that can help.

Comment: Ohh,  I posted my previous comment to the other tread above :). I forgot to ask if you have dealt with timezones as well. My code is getting super messy so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Time zone management is something I am currently looking at but have not cracked yet.

Comment: Same over here. I will let you know if I succeed. Pls, let me know if you have any valuable update.